# Do for loops implicitly create a block?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am playing with `let` in Node.JS (requires the flags `--harmony` and `--use-strict`). As I understand, the `let` statement allows for block scoped declarations. Consider the following:

```
let a;
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

How many block scopes are involved? In which block scope does `i` live in? Am I correct in thinking that for this example to work, there are *three* block scopes involved, with one scope implicitly created by the `for` loop, as follows?

```
{ // block #1
  let a;
  { // block #2 (contains `i`)
    let i;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) { // block #3
      console.log(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see what you did there.  Obviously, for clarity, you'd want to not do that in real code.  Some languages like C# actually prevent you from re-using a variable name in an inside scope (to assure clarity), even though it would work.

Comment: if you use let, you get block scope, at least in loops.

Comment: That seems to be the case, because you can declare many variables with the same name inside a function for example and it's valid with `let` but not `var`.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. The head of a `for` statement has its own scope that encompasses entire statement, so `i` is not scoped per iteration.

Comment: ...this is easy enough to test with `a=[]` outside, then `a[i]=function(){console.log(i);};` inside. Invoke the resulting functions after the loop, and there you go.

Comment: ...on second thought, I'm not sure what they actually finalized in the ES6. I know it was up for debate for a while.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the most recent (May 14, 2013) [draft of ES6](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts): yes.

You can find the following under section 12.6.3, which states that an additional *Environment* (scope) is created when a `for` statement includes a *LexicalDeclaration* (`let` or `const`):

> *IterationStatement* : **for** ( *LexicalDeclarationNoIn* ; *Expression<sub>opt</sub>* ; *Expression<sub>opt</sub>* ) *Statement*
>
> 1. Let *oldEnv* be the running execution context’s LexicalEnvironment.
> 2. **Let *loopEnv* be the result of calling NewDeclarativeEnvironment passing *oldEnv* as the argument.**
> 3. ...

Keep in mind, though, that it's still subject to change.